# java hibernate sequence

Tags: java, hibernate

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "username_sequence")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "username_sequence", sequenceName = "partner_user_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "username", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Long username;
```

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "username" violates not-null constraint

немогу понять что делаю неправильно

Comment: Ты где-то передаешь null для username

Comment: @not a Programmer нет непередаю

Comment: _null value in column "username"_ - вот этот текст из ошибки ни о чем тебе не говорит?

Comment: @not a Programmer
    Partner partner = new Partner();
    partner.setTin(partnerRequestDTO.getTin());
    partner = partnerRepository.save(partner);

Comment: Значение не устанавливается.